# Drupal7 - How to use a variable in attributes?

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

Drupal7 - How to use a variable in attributes/placeholder?

```
$form['name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    //'#maxlength' => 50,
    '#size' => 60,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#title' => t('Name'),
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => 'Max'),
);
```

The above example works, the following does not!

```
    ...
    $name = $account->field_name['und']['0']['value'];

function confirm_personal_user_information() {

    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        //'#maxlength' => 50,
        '#size' => 60,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => $name),
    );

...

}
```

Any Ideas? Thank you in advance!

Edited: ================================================
Solution: Define the variable within the form-function, however, then there's a problem with the validation...

Example:

```
function confirm_personal_user_information() {
    $name = 'Max Power';

    $form['#action'] = 'Validate';
    $form['#id'] = 'form_user_information_xxx';
    //$form['#validate'] = form_user_information_validators();
    $form['#submit'] = 'form_user_information_submit';
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="form_user_information">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

    $form['name'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        //'#maxlength' => 50,
        '#size' => 60,
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#title' => t('Name'),
        //'#attributes' => array('placeholder' => $name),
        '#default_value' => "$name",
    );

    $form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
    $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'submit', '#value' => 'Validate');

return $form;
}

//print form
$form = drupal_get_form('confirm_personal_user_information');
print drupal_render($form);
```

Comment: Same for: '#default_value' => $name,

Comment: `$name` must be empty

Comment: Hi Clive, thank you for your answer. It was not empty, however the problem was that the variable was defined outside of the form-function. If you put it within the form-function it works. See the solution I added in the post.

Comment: @NickDilis: write the answer below and mark it as the right answer for this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
'#attributes' => array(
   'class' => array('service-tax'),
   'amount' => $amt
),
```